# Handling Multiple Upload Images in React Js + Send it to Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, ecmascript-6

today I got some problem with my uploading images. I tried to upload 2 images from my front-end but on back-end got error its `Error can't sent Header after they sent`. When I just upload 1 image, I got no error but when I tried to upload 2 images, I got error. What I need to do? Should I use multipart/form-data?

I tried to use multipart/form-data but it didn't work

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class Category extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            categoryId : this.props.match.params.id,
            dataCategory:[],
            categoryName:"",
            categoryDesc:"",
            categoryImage:"",
            categoryImageCabor:"",
            namaCabor :"",
            descCabor :"",
            imgCabor :"",
            imageCabor : "",
            selectedFile: null,
            imagePreviewUrl :"",
            file:""
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.imageHandleChange = this.imageHandleChange.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getDetailsData();
    }

    getDetailsData(i){
        let categoryId = this.state.categoryId;

        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/get/${categoryId}`).then(res =>{
            if(res.status === 200)
                return res.json().then(resCategoryId =>{
                    console.log(resCategoryId);
                    this.setState({
                        id : resCategoryId._id,
                        namaCabor : resCategoryId.namaCabor,
                        descCabor : resCategoryId.descCabor,
                        imgCabor : resCategoryId.imgCabor,
                        imageCabor : resCategoryId.imageCabor
                    });
                });
            }).catch(err =>{
                if(err) console.log(err);
            })
    }


    imageHandleChange(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        reader.onloadend = () =>{
            this.setState({
                file : file,
                imagePreviewUrl : reader.result
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }


    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let {imagePreviewUrl} = this.state;
        const dataCategory = this.state.dataCategory;
        let categoryName = this.refs.categoryName.value;
        let categoryImage = this.refs.categoryImage.value;
        let categoryDesc =  this.refs.categoryDesc.value,
            categoryImageCabor = (<img alt="www.google.com" height="100px" src={imagePreviewUrl} />),
            namaCabor = this.refs.namaCabor.value,
            descCabor = this.refs.descCabor.value,
            imageCabor = (<img height="100px" src={this.state.imageCabor.props.src} />)

            fetch('http://localhost:4000/add', {
                mode:'cors',
                method:'post',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                    "Accept" : "application/json",
                    "type" : "formData"
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({
                    categoryName : categoryName,
                    categoryDesc : categoryDesc,
                    categoryImage: categoryImage,
                    categoryImageCabor : categoryImageCabor,
                    namaCabor : namaCabor,
                    descCabor : descCabor,
                    imageCabor : imageCabor,
                    status : true
                }),
            }).then(res=>{
                return res.json();
            }).catch(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })

        this.setState({
            dataCategory : dataCategory,
            imagePreviewUrl : false,
        });
        this.refs.myForm.reset();
        this.refs.myForm.focus();
    }
    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.categoryName] : e.target.value,
            [e.target.categoryImage] : e.target.value,
            [e.target.categoryDesc] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){

        let {imagePreviewUrl} = this.state;
        let $imagePreview = null;

        if(imagePreviewUrl){
            $imagePreview = (<img alt ="www.google.com" height="100px" src={imagePreviewUrl} />)
        }

        return this.state.imageCabor === "" ? <div></div> : (
            <div>
                <h3>Insert Category Cabang Olahraga </h3>
                <form style={{marginTop: 10}} ref="myForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data" >
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Nama Category</label>
                        <input
                            name="categoryName"
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            ref="categoryName"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}               
                        />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Deskripsi Category </label>
                        <textarea

                            name="categoryDesc"
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            ref="categoryDesc"
                            rows="5"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Upload Icon Image</label> <br />
                            <div>{$imagePreview}</div>
                        <input
                            name="categoryImage"
                            type="file"
                            ref="categoryImage"
                            className="image-control"
                            onChange={this.imageHandleChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <h1>Cabang Olahraga</h1>
                        <div className ="form-group">
                            <label>Nama Cabang Olahraga</label>
                        <input 
                            name="namaCabor"
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            ref="namaCabor"
                            value={this.state.namaCabor}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className ="form-group">
                            <label>Deskripsi Cabang Olahraga</label>
                        <textarea
                            name="descCabor"
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            ref="descCabor"
                            rows="5"
                            value={this.state.descCabor}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Icon Cabang Olahraga</label> <br />
                            <div><img height="100px" src={this.state.imageCabor.props.src} /></div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Apply" className ="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Category;
```

In my back-end got output. Error can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: can you post the backend code?

Comment: ```app.post('/add', function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.body);
    // upload(req, res, (err)=>{

    const {categoryName, categoryDesc, categoryImage, categoryImageCabor, namaCabor, descCabor, imageCabor } = req.body;
    connectDb.collection('listCategoryCabangOlahraga').insertOne(req.body, function(err, result){
        console.log(result.insertedCount +'data inserted'); 
        if(err) console.log(err);
    }, res.send(req.body));
    
});```

Comment: sorry thats my backend its like mess if i copy here

Comment: If you are using `mutler` then please add the initiation of `upload` variable

Comment: alright thank you brother! i'll try, first thing i need to learn about multer first lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the formData to the server using FormData something like this

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (const file of this.state.files) {
  formData.append('file', file)
  formData.append('file2', file2)
  formData.append('file3', file3)
}
```

or you can write in easy way

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file)
formData.append('file2', file2)
formData.append('file3', file3)
```

Please change accordingly with your code

Make sure to set the header to `multipart/form-data` too

Cheers

Comment: where should i put that variable formData?

Comment: In the place you submit the data to the server

Comment: i already tried to add formData but i got error that this.state.file its not iterable, sry im new to react js btw :(

Comment: Check my answer again and please adapt my code with your. Dont just copy and paste

Comment: i got it man, thanks. i have one question what did i need to add in node for uploading multiple images? i already reading that i need to use multer, is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Tony's answer is good enough, here are few things from my end
to add multiple files:

you need to use formdata for this

```
var data = new FormData();
for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    data.append("files" + x, files[x]);
}
```

to handle in nodejs: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

I would suggest following library for enhancement (since they are specialised library one can always benefit from them)

Dropzone(for file uploads): https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone
you can add restrictions by file size type etc

Axios(library for http request): https://github.com/axios/axios
Convenient than using fetch